# DB2 & SQL Table Views

Tags: db2, sql-view

I am attempting to pull some information from a DB2 table to be inputted into an SQL view/ table. I have the AQT application and the Primary key is an account number in both the SQL and DB2 table.

An example would be a db2 with the account number and customer name. The information I'm looking to add to my SQL view is the customer name from that db2 table

Where would I start to enable this to happen automatically on a daily basis?

Comment: you need to describe the question better, add some sample data and desired output and maybe add what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run something on a regular schedule in DB2 you can either use external services like `cron` or the built-in [DB2 Administrative Task Scheduler](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.gui.doc/doc/c0054380.html). The latter has some SQL interfaces, uses the built-in security, and can be monitored.